# Combining two excel files based on column names of the new file

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

*Hi everyone*,
I have **two excel files** of September and October and I want to have both files in a **single worksheet**. I need to have all columns that are in October file and delete additional columns of September. Could you please help me how to do that?

Thanks!

Comment: We will need some more details. 1) How many sheets are in each workbook? 2) Do you need all the data within them or just part of them? 3) If it's the latter, how can we determinate what part do you want? 4) Do you want to rearrange the data once in the new sheet? 5) Is a VBA solution fine for you?

Comment: 1) There is only one sheet in each workbook. 2) I want to copy only columns that are in previous version and remove additional columns from new file version.4) Yes, I want to rearrange two excel files into one excel file. 5) I don't know about VBA.

Answer (score 0):

For 2007+ use `Data` > From `Other Sources` > From `Microsoft Query`:

choose `Excel File` and select your 1st excel
choose columns
(if you don't see any list of columns, make sure to check Options > System Tables)
go to `Data` > `Connections` > [choose the connection just created] > `Properties` > `Definition` > `Command text`
You can now edit this `Command text` as SQL. Not sure what syntax is suported, but I tried implicit joins, "inner join", "left join" and unions which all work. Here is a sample query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `C:\Users\Peter\Documents\Excel-to-excel\Source_1.xlsx`.`Sheet1$` a
LEFT JOIN `C:\Users\Peter\Documents\Excel-to-excel\Source_2.xlsx`.`Sheet1$` b
ON a.col2 = b.col2
```